# Connect to a local db from testcomplete

Tags: javascript, database, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, testcomplete

I am trying make a query from test complete to an Oracle db.

This is what I have so far:

```
function main (){
  var result = query("select * from appsettings where settingid = 10")

  function query (sqlQuery) {
  var dbObj = ADO.CreateADOQuery();
  dbObj.ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source='localhost:1521/ORCL';User Id='someUser';Password='somePass';OLEDB.NET=True;";

  dbObj.SQL = sqlQuery;
  dbObj.Open();
  queryResult = dbObj;
  return queryResult;
  }

  Log.Message("Query result is: " + result)
}
```

The problem is that result has no value.. and the message I get is:

> Query result is:

Answer (score 0):

The query object cannot be printed itself. You need to get data from the object. For example:

```
...
sqlQuery.First();
while (!sqlQuery.EOF) {
  Log.Message(sqlQuery.FieldByName("FirstName").Value + " " + sqlQuery.FieldByName("LastName").Value);
  sqlQuery.Next();
};
sqlQuery.Close();
```